# checkbox not working with multiple checkbox onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, onclick

```js
function myFunction(){
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
}}
```

```html
Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox 1 is CHECKED!</p>
<br>
Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox 2 is CHECKED!</p>
```

**I want both check boxes to work after clicking one by one on it.**
**The result I get: only checkbox 1 is working, the other is not working.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` attribute has to be unique so in this case `getElementById` only selects the first element. you can change the `id` attribute to `class` and then select your checkboxes and paragraphs with `getElementsByClassName`.

```
Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<p class="text" style="display:none">Checkbox 1 is CHECKED!</p>
<br>
Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<p class="text" style="display:none">Checkbox 2 is CHECKED!</p>
```

Now the JavaScript part need to recognize the checkboxes. We should add a FOR loop to select the checkbox[i] and the paragraph below it.

```
for (var i=0;i<checkBox.length; i++) {
    if (checkBox[i].checked == true){
    text[i].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

[See the Demo here](https://codepen.io/mostafa-es/pen/eYYKjwa?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2):

Give different Id .It will works.

```js
function myFunction(){
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
}}

function myFunction1(){
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck1");
  var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text1.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text1.style.display = "none";
}}
```

```html
Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox 1 is CHECKED!</p>
<br>
Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="myFunction1()">

<p id="text1" style="display:none">Checkbox 2 is CHECKED!</p>
```

Comment: If it is work for you then please up-vote and accept the answer.

Comment: unable to upvote --> thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.